# Specify a folder for scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to specify an output folder for scaffolding? In the example below I would like the generated context file placed in the "DataAccess" folder

```
Scaffold DbContext Product WebAPIContext -Folder DataAccess
```

This returns the following error:

```
Invoke-Scaffolder : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Folder'.At line:1 
char:49
+ Scaffold DbContext Product WebAPIContext -Folder <<<<  DataAccess
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Scaffolder], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet
```

Is this supported?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Have you figured this out?  Thanks